# Passing Parameter from SQL-File to procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Sadly I don't know the exact names for each part, probably I can explain it:
We have a SQL-File, which is defined like this:

```
declare
l_exec boolean := true;
l_print boolean := false;
---  
begin
dbms_output.enable;
for t in (
```

And so on. We use this to create some Triggers etc. in our Oracle-Database.
Now this File grew to much and I need to split it up.
So I created a Main-File, which is looking like this:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT on
set feedback off

DEFINE  l_exec  = TRUE;
DEFINE  l_print = FALSE;

ACCEPT ora_instance PROMPT "Zielinstanz angeben [123|...]: " DEFAULT somedefault

CONNECT somelogins

PROMPT  -- GENERATING CODE --
@file1 l_print, l_exec
```

This would work fine, but I'd like to pass the l_exec and l_print to each file. I read in some other Threads passing the parameters like this is ok. But the problem is: I not only need to pass it from file to file, but I need to pass it to the Procedure-Block after begin.

I'm not sure if I made it understandable, but I'd like to use the variable I pass at @file1 in the begin block of the Files.

Is this kindahow possible? I googled alot about SQLPlus, but didn't find a solution so far.

Thanks as always and a nice week

Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so if your main file has the call to your sub-file:

```
...
CONNECT somelogins

PROMPT  -- GENERATING CODE --
@file1 l_print, l_exec
```

then your sub-file can use the parameters in a positional manner thus:

```
declare
l_print boolean := &1;
l_exec  boolean := &2;
---  
begin
dbms_output.enable;
for t in (
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I added SET DEFINE ON and now it is working. And on the @file1 I hadd to use the &l_print syntax.

Comment: @MatthiasMüller - glad you got there in the end =)